# SQL Query getting escaped characters inserted

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a query thats being fed into MySQL. I added a new component.. a `LIKE`.
It works fine for a singular item, but when I pass in multiples... it does some weird escape of the single quotes. 
Here is what the sql passed in looks like (from the console.log below):

```
sql: 'select name, street, numbers from' +
     "`HOMES` where " +
     "year='2020' and vals in ('2.2.3\\',\\'2.4.5')",
values: [ '2020', "2.2.3','2.4.5"]
```

Here is how I build the `vals`:

```
sql += " and vals in (?)";
var newStr = filterText.myItems.split(",".join("','");
sqlParams.push(newStr);
```

`filterText.myItems` is entered by the user as a comma separated value. For example: "`2.2.3,2.4.5`"

The query going into MySQL is built like this:

```
exports.query = function(sql, params, resultHandler, errorHandler) {
  function _handleError(err) {
     errorHandler(config.mysql.errorMessage || err); 
  }
  pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    if(err) {
      _handleError(err);
      return;
    }
    var query22 = conn.query(sql, params, function(err,results) {
       if(err) {
          _handleError(err);
       } else {
          resultHandler(results);
       }

       conn.release();
    });
    //this prints out the sql and values displayed above.
    console.log("FINAL QUERY:"+util.inspect(query22));
  }
}
```

Needless to say... this fails to execute as I guess MySQL has no idea what the `\\'` actually is.
For whatever reason the query adds the leading and trailing single quotes. This is why I add the `','` in between the numbers.

Anyone know what might be causing this or how I can remove it before it executes?

thanks!

Comment: `'from  'HOMES' where ' +` there is a + missing here. It should be `'from  '+HOMES+' where ' +`

Comment: @MarceloTheWizzardCoder I mistyped it. Looks like that line and line below it had double quotes... where as other line had single quotes. Not really sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around some more I finally got it to work. Here is how.
The sql was built and params passed in like this:

```
 sql = "select name, street, numbers from ?? where year=?",
 sqlParams = [this.tableName, this.year]
```

I was dynamically adding to my sql with the `in` clause. However, when I made it part of the main sql and passed in the vals there it worked!

```
 sql = "select name, street, numbers from ?? where year=? and vals in (?)",
 sqlParams = [this.tableName, this.year,  filterText.myItems.split(',')]
```

The sql going in now looks like this and works great:

```
sql: 'select name, street, numbers from' +
 "`HOMES` where " +
 "year='2020' and vals in ('2.2.3','2.4.5')",
values: [ '2020', ['2.2.3','2.4.5'] ]
```